# express app.use not working when using it inside a class

Tags: typescript, express, class

I'm building a `WebServer` class that will create either a HTTP or HTTPS express webserver.
The abstract class is aimed to set some defaults to the express server and the child class that extends it will add some settings depending if the server is http or https.

However, I have noticed that when using `this.app.use(whateveroption)` in the abstract class when instantiating the server, the `whateveroption` is `app.use` is not set. In the below example the api router is not accessable (calling the endpoint is ending with a timeout, and helmet and morgan are also not set.
However, the endpoint `/isalive` is working well.
Do I miss something important here ?

**FIXED** : I made typo mistake in `this._app.use(express.json())`. typed `this._app.use(express.json)` instead of `this._app.use(express.json())`

**abstract class**

```
abstract class WebServer {
  private _app: Express;
  private _routers: IWebServerRoute[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this._applyDefaultToExpressApp();
  }


  private _applyDefaultToExpressApp() {
    this._app = express();
    this._app.get("/isalive", (_, res: Response) => res.status(200).json({ status: "I'm alive" })); // <== endpoint is OK
    const apiRouter = Router();
    apiRouter.get("/root", (_, res: Response) => res.status(200).json({ status: "from api root" }));
    this._app.use("/api", apiRouter); // <== timeout when calling localhost:5500/api/root
    this._app.use(express.json);
    this._app.use(
      express.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
      })
    );
    this._app.use(helmet());
    this._app.use(morgan("dev")); // <== no morgan logs in the console
  }

  public get app(): Express {
    return this._app;
  }


  abstract createWebServer(serverOptions: http.ServerOptions | https.ServerOptions): http.Server | https.Server;
}
```

**HTTPWebServer children class**

```
class HTTPWebServer extends WebServer {
  public server: http.Server;
  constructor(httpOptions?: THTTPWebServerOptions | undefined) {
    super();
  }
  public createWebServer(serverOptions?: http.ServerOptions | undefined): http.Server {
    if (serverOptions) {
      this.server = http.createServer(serverOptions, this.app);
    } else {
      this.server = http.createServer(this.app);
    }
    return this.server;
  }
}
```

**Example of usage**

```
 const webServer = new HTTPWebServer();
const server = webServer.createWebServer();
    
      server.listen(port, async () => {
        console.log(`server listen to ${port}`);
      });
```

Comment: find the solution, that indeed was a typo mistake... Have edited the initial post with the fix

Comment: fix inside the initial question is not a bad practice...

Comment: I'm not how sure your position is informed but it's in direct contradiction to the [self-answering article in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

FIXED : I made typo mistake in `this._app.use(express.json())`. typed `this._app.use(express.json)` instead of `this._app.use(express.json())`